# Finding child element of parent with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

What would be the most efficient method to find a child element (with class or ID) of a particular parent element using pure javascript only. No jQuery or other frameworks.

In this case, I would need to find **child1** or **child2** of **parent**, assuming that the DOM tree could have multiple **child1** or **child2** class elements in the tree. I only want the elements of **parent**

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        <div class="child2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815374/get-element-inside-element-by-class-and-id-javascript

Comment: ID would be the easiest way. They have to be unique, so you can just do `document.getElementById('element-id')`.

Comment: Use regular dom queries, then: read this [best way to get child nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes)

Answer (score 237, accepted):

The `children` property returns an array of elements, like so:

```
parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
children = parent.children; // [<div class="child1">]
```

There are alternatives to `querySelector`, like `document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0]` if you so desire.

---

Edit: Now that I think about it, you could just use `querySelectorAll` to get decendents of `parent` having a class name of `child1`:

```
children = document.querySelectorAll('.parent .child1');
```

The difference between qS and qSA is that the latter returns *all* elements matching the selector, while the former only returns the first such element.

Comment: I know this answer is 10+ years old, but because it might be still found on Google... Technically, `children` doesn't return an `array`, but an `HTMLCollection`. As in `Array.isArray(document.children) == false`. You need to use `Array.from(document.children)` to convert it to a proper array.

Answer (score 360):

If you already have `var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');` you can do this to scope the search to `parent`'s children:

```js
parent.querySelector('.child')
```

Comment: You can also `parent.querySelectorAll('.child')` to return a NodeList

Answer (score 30):

Just adding another idea you could use a child selector to get immediate children

```
document.querySelectorAll(".parent > .child1");
```

should return all the immediate children with class .child1

Comment: I've been seeing everyone suggest querySelector than getElementBy**. Is it more efficient?

Comment: Maybe this will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid

Comment: This will not return `.child2`, and other children, as asked by @Blyde

Answer (score 22):

[Element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) is the best way;

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent'); 
// Do anything next //When you want
parent.querySelector('.child1'); // <div class="child1">
```

Comment: When I use query selector against a parent that has three img elements that all have .img-fluid only the first img element is returned. How can I select all ?

Comment: @b_dubb you can use querySelectorAll instead to get all elements

Answer (score 3):

You have a parent element, you want to get all child of specific attribute
 1. get the parent
 2. get the parent nodename by using `parent.nodeName.toLowerCase()` convert the nodename to lower case e.g DIV will be div
 3. for further specific purpose, get an attribute of the parent e.g `parent.getAttribute("id")`. this will give you `id` of the parent
 4. Then use `document.QuerySelectorAll(paret.nodeName.toLowerCase()+"#"_parent.getAttribute("id")+" input "  );`  if you want input children of the parent node

```js
let parent = document.querySelector("div.classnameofthediv")
let parent_node = parent.nodeName.toLowerCase()
let parent_clas_arr = parent.getAttribute("class").split(" ");
let parent_clas_str = '';
  parent_clas_arr.forEach(e=>{
     parent_clas_str +=e+'.';
  })
let parent_class_name = parent_clas_str.substr(0, parent_clas_str.length-1)  //remove the last dot
let allchild = document.querySelectorAll(parent_node+"."+parent_class_name+" input")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use to get parent

```
let parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
```

use parent to get a specific child

```
let child1 = parent.querySelectorAll('.child');
```

All children can be fetched using

```
let  childrens = parent.children;
```

we can get single child by index as well

```
let secondChild = parent.children[1]
```