# Efficient workaround instead of using numerous if statements?

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

What is a better workaround to this, rather than repeating the if statement numerous times for 10 different elements?

Html:

```
 <div id="rightWrongContainer">
        <div id="q1" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q2" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q3" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q4" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q5" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q6" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q7" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q8" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q9" class="rightWrong"></div>
        <div id="q10" class="rightWrong"></div>
    </div>
```

Js:

```
     if (counter == 1 && answer == userInput){
            var green = document.getElementById("q1").style.backgroundColor="green";
          }
          else {
            var red = document.getElementById("q1").style.backgroundColor="red";
          }
    if (counter == 2 && answer == userInput){
            var green = document.getElementById("q2").style.backgroundColor="green";
          }
          else {
            var red = document.getElementById("q2").style.backgroundColor="red";
          }

    if (counter == 3 && answer == userInput){
            var green = document.getElementById("q3").style.backgroundColor="green";
          }
          else {
            var red = document.getElementById("q3").style.backgroundColor="red";
          }
```

and so on...

Edit: 
see this image [My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnz6I.jpg)

Each time a user submits their answer, I want the divs (circles in image link) to change according to if the answer is correct hence 'answer == userInput' but also the right div has to equal the right number of question so I have created a counter so I know what question the user is on but i dont want to create an if statement for every element ' counter == 1 , counter == 2 and so on...

Comment: I don't get your question

Comment: Is there a relation between `answer` and `counter`? I would say: yes; please specify/clarify.

Comment: whether each div has an input and a submit button ?

Comment: @messerbill I have added a little more information to my question

Comment: @PeterB answer is a value which checks the outcome of a maths sum, counter is keeping track of how many questions they have done by adding +1 each time they answer a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the .children property to access an HTMLCollection of elements within a selected element. in your example you can do

```
var elemList = document.getElementById("rightWrongContainer").children;
```

I wrote up an example for you on how to use this: http://jsfiddle.net/30u847gL/

Also, some light reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children

Happy Coding!

Comment: In your fiddle: Why use `getElementById()` when you already have all the elements?

Comment: Mmm vanilla js isnt my strongsuit. Im more used to jQuery. XD

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the problem, but this can be a solution

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#rightWrongContainer>.rightWrong');

items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.backgroundColor = answer == userInput ? 'green' : 'red'
}
```

Comment: The approach is rather promising, but as written, either all items will become green or all will become red.

Comment: `items.forEach( (item, i) => item.style.backgroundColor = (answer==userInput && counter==i) ? 'green' : 'red')`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a group of elements by either [finding the children of a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16302045/6660678):

```
var qs = document.getElementById("rightWrongContainer").children;
```

or by [getting elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17965956/6660678):

```
var qs = document.getElementsByClassName("rightWrong");
```

You can [iterate over a group of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/157260/6660678) by a number of methods, e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; qs[i]; i++) {
    if (counter == i + 1 && answer == userInput) {
        qs[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        qs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```