# Get elements by class name in a certain div through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have:

```html
<div class="f0">
    <div class="input-text">
        <t>Text</t>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
var h = 0;
    for(h;h<inputstext.length;h++){
        var str = 'f' + h;
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById(str);


    }
```

How do I get only the `input-text` elements value that is in `f0`?

Output should be **`Text`**.

Thanks.

Comment: what is inputstext ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Finding child element of parent pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302045/finding-child-element-of-parent-pure-javascript)

Comment: @GuyIncognito He's wanting to grab classes that match `f*`, not just iterate over children.

Comment: That's what the code already does. "How do I get only the input-text elements value that is in f0?"

Comment: @GuyIncognito I have multiple: f0, f1, f2, f3, f4 etc. But i only want the `input-group` data from `f0`.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want. The duplicate shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `element[property*="val"]` to select all `elements` with `property` beginning with `"val"` - in this case, any `class` that starts with `"f"`, and then select their `.input-text` children.

Also, you're trying to get elements with **id** `f0`, when these divs are marked with **class** `f0`.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="f"] .input-text');
for (const element of inputs)
  console.log(element.textContent.trim());
```

```html
<div class="f0">
    <div class="input-text">
        inside f0
    </div>
</div>
<div class="f1">
    <div class="input-text">
        inside f1
    </div>
</div>
```