# is there a way to display the child items of the selected parent of the div? looking for pure JavaScript solution..(not using Jquery or any library)

Tags: javascript, html

below is the current solution that i have developed..

```
<script>
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
  var myFunction = function() {
      var childNode = document.querySelector('.child');
      if(childNode.style.display == "block")
        childNode.style.display = "none";
      else
        childNode.style.display = "block";
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
  }
</script>
```

below link has the entire code...
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DayakarKodirekka/dqjmLt0h/1/)
currently its displays only one row item of p1 even when i click on any of he options p1, p2, p3 and p4..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302045/finding-child-element-of-parent-with-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding child element of parent with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302045/finding-child-element-of-parent-with-javascript)

Comment: You should change `document` to `this` in : `var childNode = document.querySelector('.child');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the parent from the `click` event and use `querySelectorAll` to get the childs of the target of the event (the parent), then iterate over the childs to check if they should be displayed or hidden.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .child {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <table></table>
  <div class="parent">p1
    <div class="child">p1 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p1 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p1 Some content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">p2
    <div class="child">p2 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p2 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p2 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p2 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p2 Some content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">p3
    <div class="child">p3 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p3 Some content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">p4
    <div class="child">p4 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p4 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p4 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p4 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p4 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p4 Some content</div>
    <div class="child">p4 Some content</div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
  var myFunction = function(ev) {
    var childNodes = ev.target.querySelectorAll('.child');
    childNodes.forEach(child => {
      if (child.style.display == "block")
        child.style.display = "none";
      else
        child.style.display = "block";
    })
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the solution, i have edited the question a bit, could you pls suggest how to display the child class items? https://jsfiddle.net/DayakarKodirekka/dqjmLt0h/4/