# Get div id inside another div id with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

*Edited to explain page loading*

My HTML page has a div inside another div, both referenced by id, and both unique throughout the document.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
...
<body onload=display()>
<div id="rightwork">
<div id="mychart" > </div>
</div>
...
```

My JavaScript is meant to write something within the 'mychart' div, but I can't manage to reference it :(

The question is related to [this one except this one is a class inside an id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815374/get-element-inside-element-by-class-and-id-javascript).

This is my javascript:

```
function display() {
    var code = "<a onclick=\"second(); return false;\" href=\"#\">Hello</a>";
    document.getElementById('rightwork').innerHTML = code;
}

function second() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('rightwork'));
    console.log(document.getElementById('mychart'));
}
```

The line

```
document.getElementById("mychart");
```

returns null...

Whereas, this one works fine!

```
document.getElementById("rightwork");
```

This returns the expected div.

I attempted this

```
document.getElementById("rightwork").getElementById("mychart");
```

which of course does not work as getElementById("rightwork") returns a single element.

So, what's the solution to reference the inner div?

Comment: If document is loaded correctly why document.getElementById("mychart"); would not work?

Comment: Be aware that `id` must be *unique* as per-document.

Comment: @eomeroff you are right actually: I found the error: the HTML I display is generated by function display() and that one does not have getElementById... 
If I modify var code to:

         var code = "<div id=\"mychart\"><a onclick=\"second(); return false;\" href=\"#\">Hello</a></div>";

It will work.
Yet, I wonder why rightwork is found in second() ?

Comment: @user1381 plase check in browser what html was rendered in #rightwork div. I bealive you are replacing #mychard div with content: <a onclick=\"second(); return false;\" href=\"#\">Hello</a>

Comment: @user1381 was my last comment helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
window.onload = function(){
   var myChart = document.getElementById("mychart");
   // ... code that loads chart
}
```

Or move

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

to the page footer to insure the dom is loaded before running the script

Comment: You are right that this is a page loading issue, although your solution does not solve my particular case (edited). See my comment to eomeroff, I was missing the mychart id in the HTML code I was generating after a click.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post whole myscript.js content. If document is loaded correctly why `document.getElementById("mychart");` would not work?

The thing might be that `<div id="mychart" > </div>` is not loaded while javascript is executed and `<div id="rightwork">` was loaded in that time.

To ensure the document is fully loaded put your `<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>` at the end of html.