# Javascript to get link text

Tags: javascript

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2" id="myName1">
  <p>
    <a href="/something/121212">Get This Text</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

The question is how do I get the text "Get this Text"

Something like this, but getting that text which is wrapped in the `p` and `a` tags:

```
function () {
  return document.getElementById('TextID');
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7815388/901048 is very similar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search for the first `p` inside your `myName1` element, then the first `a` within that.

```js
var e = document.getElementById('myName1').
        getElementsByTagName('p')[0].
        getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

var theText = e.innerHTML;

console.log(theText);

// or, in sufficiently-modern browsers

e = document.querySelector('#myName1 p a');
theText = e.innerHTML;

console.log( theText );
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2" id="myName1">
<p>
<a href="/something/121212">Get This Text</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In this specific case, he doesn't even need to search for the first `p`.

Comment: No, but the question specified "that text which is wrapped in the p and a tags", so we had to pick *a* `p` element to search within.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using `document.getElementById('anchorID').text`; assuming anchor has id of `anchorID`. The `text` property sets or returns the text content of a link.

**EDIT 1** : If you are not able to add the ID, then you need to take long path by going to document.getElementByID and then reach to the element using the `document.getElementsByTagName`

```js
  var myAnchor = document.getElementById("myName1").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  console.log(myAnchor.text);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2" id="myName1">
<p>
<a id="anchorID" href="/something/121212">Get This Text</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is that there is no `id` on the `a` tag and I can't add one.

Comment: in that case, you can use the `document.getElementById("myName1").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]` to get all the anchor elements and then get the first element (assuming you have only 1 anchor tag). Updated the post.

Comment: As MDN doesn't document `aElement.text`, I was wondering if it is standard HTML; indeed it is: According to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-a-text ,  `aElement.text` is the same as `anyElement.textContent`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following in your function:

```
return document.querySelector('#myName1 p a').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the get element by tag name method, but it returns an array of results so you will have to consider that, in your example, this works...

```js
var a=document.getElementById('myName1');
console.log(a.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2" id="myName1">
<p>
<a href="/something/121212">Get This Text</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, you can use ***innerHtml*** attribute

```
<script>
function gettext()
{
    return document.getElementById('link').innerHTML;
}

</script>
 <div class="col-md-2" id="myName1">
<p>
<a href="/something/121212" id="link">Get This Text</a>
</p>
</div>
<script>
alert(gettext());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using JQuery
    `$("#myName1 p a").text();`