# How can you get a href from an innerhtml with multiple tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to access the contents of a specific tag within innerHTML? 
I have a div tag that I can access with `document.getelementbyclass()`. It has nested tags within it and would like to pull a href from one of these nested tags. What would be the best way to get the link from the following example?

```
<div class="MyClass">
    <h5> Some text I dont want </h5>
    <a href="http://IwantThisLink.com"> http://IwantThisLink.com </a>
</div>
```

Comment: what if you add `class` or `id` to the href itself?

Comment: or you could use [:nth child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)>a  (but I second the adding of an id)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815374/get-element-inside-element-by-class-and-id-javascript

Comment: @AviThour, did you mean add a class to the _anchor_? Or did you mean to somehow append a string to the `href` attribute's value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short call with JQuery, can be done with vanilla JS if needed.

```js
alert($(".MyClass a").attr("href"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MyClass">
    <h5> Some text I dont want </h5>
    <a href="http://IwantThisLink.com"> http://IwantThisLink.com </a>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no jQuery tag up there.

Answer (score 2):

You can as well use querySelector

```
document.querySelector('.MyClass a').getAttribute('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are asking.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('MyClass')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href
```

Be careful with `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName`.  They will always return a collection (an array) of HTML tags, even if that collection has one item.  Accessing the array with `[0]` will give you the first item.  If there are other elements with a "MyClass" class, you will only be selecting the first one.  This can cause some unexpected behavior.

If something is important enough to be accessed by JavaScript, you should probably give it an `id` attribute and access it with `getElementById`.  For example:

```html
<div class="my-class">
    <h5> Some text I dont want </h5>
    <a id="important-link" href="http://IwantThisLink.com"> http://IwantThisLink.com </a>
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById('search').href
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated

```
document.querySelector('.MyClass a').setAttribute('href', 'google.com');
```

Comment: document.querySelector('.MyClass a').setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com');

Comment: You'd want to update your answer, not put changes in comments. :)